# Unable to hide php extension from live server

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I have added below code in .htaccess but its not working....

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^websparrow.org [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.websparrow.org/$1 [L,R=301]
```

I want to hide .php extension from the url and redirect a non www to www.

I have removed the .php from href and got 404 error.

Can somebody help me... here is my website link for review...

[enter link description here](http://www.websparrow.org)

Answer (score 0):

## remove the php extension from your links

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s([^.]+)\.php [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1 [R=301,L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*?)/?$ $1.php [NC,L]
```

## redirect non-www to www

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^websparrow.org\.org$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.websparrow.org/$1 [L,R=301]
```

Both codes have been tested on my CentOS 6.8 server, running php-5.5.x and apache 2.2.x